# Difference between SetupSet and SetupProperty in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I understand that SetupSet is old way of setting up property in Moq. It's obsolette now but my intellisense shows both with none of them marked Obsolette. Can anyone point me the actual difference between them?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I probably found one of the difference as follows.

If you are trying to mock a Readonly property, you have to use SetupGet as SetupProperty doesn't work in that case. Whereas SetupProperty can be used for non readonly properties if you want to set expectation.

For example, below won't work

```
public interface IXyz
{
  int Id { get; }
}

//Test Side Code    
var _mock = new Mock<IXyz>();
_mock.SetupProperty(x => x.Id, 1054);
```

If you try executing above code, it will come up saying
System.ArgumentException: Property IXyz.Id is read-only

So if you change the code to below, it will work

```
_mock.SetupGet(x => x.Id).Returns(1054);
```

Comment: Suggest editing this into the end of your answer - its what everyone else does

Comment: I don't think it is 100% correct. According to the documentation, SetupProperty is used for stubbing, not to set expectations.

Answer (score 16):

[SetupSet](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties) is not marked obsolete.  You might be thinking of [ExpectSet](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/8596fdce1aeb9c0276cdb93ce1a81f7b0e7064c4/Source/Obsolete/Mock.Generic.Legacy.cs#L89), which is marked as obsolete with the message, *"ExpectSet has been renamed to SetupSet."*

`SetupSet` lets you indicate an expectation that the property will be set:

```
mock.SetupSet(x => x.Prop = "bar").Verifiable();
mock.Object.Prop = "foo";
mock.Verify();   // fails
```

`SetupProperty` looks like a way to stub a property on the mock (see the same section of the documentation as for `SetupSet`).

Comment: Yeah, I thought that SetupProperty acts both for getter and setter but then what is SetupSet used for?

Comment: @Nimesh, I added an example of using `SetupSet` to verify that the property setter was called.

Comment: @adrift, currently none of the links are working. Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Links are dead.  Four Hundred and Four.

Comment: @Bomboca:  sorry I missed your earlier comment!